# Option value reset

Tags: php, forms, validation

Trying to figure out why the selected option value is removed after the form fails validation (specifically an incorrect captcha).

If a user enters an incorrect captcha, the option value selected prior to submitting is erased and defaults back to the first value.

```
<select name="How-soon-are-you-looking-to-invest-in-a-franchise" />
<option value="Within-6-months" <?php if ($_POST["Within-6-months"]=="Within-6-months"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Within the next 6 months</option>
<option value="Six-twelve-months" <?php if ($_POST["Six-twelve-months"]=="Six-twelve-months"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>6-12 months</option>
<option value="Twelve-or-more-months" <?php if ($_POST["Twelve-or-more-months"]=="Twelve-or-more-months"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>More than 12 months</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: some code would be nice :p

Comment: Sorry - brain freeze 0 it is there now.

Comment: try echoing 'selected="selected"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form variable names are transferred, so your conditions should look like:

```
<option value="Within-6-months" <?php if ($_POST["How-soon-are-you-looking-to-invest-in-a-franchise"]=="Within-6-months"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Within the next 6 months</option>
```

So in a nutshell, use `$_POST["How-soon-are-you-looking-to-invest-in-a-franchise"]`, not `$_POST["Within-6-months"]`